# Question about implementing abstract functions in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning and testing a piece of C++ code as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
class Shape {
public:
    Shape() {};
    ~Shape() {};
    virtual void display() const = 0;
    virtual double volume() const = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
public:
    Square() {};
    ~Square() {};
    void display() const;
    double volume() const;
};

void Square::display() const {
    cout << "Square!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;
}
double Square::volume() const {
    cout << "Square Volume........." << endl;
    return 0.0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Shape *s;
    s = new Square; // error here
    (*s).display();

    return 0;
}
```

The above code does not compile successfully. it produces: "**fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals**".
Can anyone help me out with that?
I am using MS VS C++ 2005.
Thanks

Comment: There should be more detailed messages above that LNK1120 error showing exactly what the missing symbol is. Please provide those as well.

Comment: This example compiles fine for me on VS 2010.

Comment: Don't forget to make your destructor virtual (I don't think this is your problem, but it is A problem).

Comment: The standard `main` is `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` (or `int main()` if you don't use those arguments). Drop that VC++-only nonsense. And you don't need `conio.h`.

Comment: As implied by @Zilchonum's comment, this looks to me like a problem either with how you've installed or used the compiler, not with the code (at least not the code you've posted). That's not to say the code's perfect, but I don't see anything that should give an unresolved external.

Comment: Side note: don't write `(*s).display()`. Use `s->display()` instead.

Comment: Thanks all. I created a new project and copied the same code, it worked. Weird,ah??

Answer (score 1):

The above code compiles and runs properly on VS 2010 as well as Ideone.

Check [this](http://www.ideone.com/1FItd)

There is nothing wrong in the way you have implemented your abstract functions in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is your main declaration.

If you change it to a standard main definition, I believe your linking problems will be fixed.

```
 int main()
 {
   Shape *s = new Square(); // error here
   s->display();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: He is using MSVC++2005. So that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @Nawaz Indeed, but it's still bad practice unless one is explicitely targeting Windows.

Comment: Never used VS, didn't realize they can use this non standard main declaration.

Comment: @Etienne: Bad practice is one thing, and saying that is the problem is another.

Comment: @Brian It actually comes from the Win32 API, IIRC.

Comment: @Etienne, it's bad practice period - new programs should be using the unicode APIs exclusively. _tmain() was useful when people needed to be able to make one build targetting unicode windows NT, and another targetting non-unicode windows 9x from the same codebase, but it really shouldn't be used anymore.